# Excel set all column text to one value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a problem with Excel.
I have added an extra column to my data, and I want to set all the rows of the column equal to the string "Male".

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: If you're looking for a keyboard shortcut checkout [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425210/shortcut-to-apply-a-formula-to-an-entire-column-in-excel)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Enter "Male" in the first cell then select it and all the cells beneath it you want filled, then press Ctrl + D to fill down.

Comment: @Parhs Perhaps mark the answer as correct then.

Comment: If your excel file has a lot of rows, don't forget that ctrl+end gets to the bottom.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + End and then Ctrl + D did the trick for me