# How to set a whole row equal to a value, using ARRAYFORMULA() ? (in Google Sheets)

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I would like to set the contents of all cells in a particular row to have the same value, sort of like having a banner that runs across the entire width of the spreadsheet. I'm working in Google Sheets.

A similar question [was asked here](https://superuser.com/questions/204233/excel-set-all-column-text-to-one-value), but I would like to do this dynamically. The actual content I want will never change, but the spreadsheet I'm using often has columns added to it. I would like every column in this row to display the same text, without me having to manually copy it over every time columns are added.

### Specific scenario

Starting with D1, I want all cells in row 1 (to the right of D1) to contain the text, "Banner text".
I've found a way to sort of make this work (below), but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution that doesn't break the spreadsheet.

### What I've done so far

In D1, I have the formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:2=$A$2,"Banner text","Banner text"))
```

This seems deeply confuse Google Sheets. When I enter the formula, the cell contents rapidly flash between:

- `Banner text` in all the necessary cells
- `#REF!` in just the cell with the formula, claiming there's a circular dependency

for a few seconds and then randomly(?) lands on one of them. I'm curious as to why it thinks there's a circular dependency, but my main concern is just a clean and simple solution to the original problem.

Comment: [ A similar question _was asked here_, but I would like to do this dynamically. ] It is better to refers to exact question/ topic, than to _search list_, please.  And, it can be good to look for the answer on  https://webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: I posted the wrong link by mistake. Fixed now.
I have searched on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/, but couldn't find anything related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Formula in D1

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(D2:2/0,"Banner text"))
```

Creates an array of errors from the range `D2:2` and uses IFERROR to replace them with "Banner text".

Dividing a cell by zero returns one of two errors based on its contents:

1. `#DIV/0!` if a number or equivalent *****
2. `#VALUE!` if a text string

***** Can be coerced to a number, such as a blank cell (zero), or a text string that matches one of the locale's number formats.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of clever solution I was looking for. Thanks for your help.